# PUT request not working with web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

We are having some issue with Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) implementation in a restfull web service on web2py.

We try to implement CORS on the server side in web2py as suggested here: ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/kSUtyNcUQGI/qfiIqfUiWLwJ )

We added following to models/0.py, (to have the response header updated before actual restfull api handler in the controler)

===============================

```
if request.env.http_origin:
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.env.http_origin
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = 86400

    if request.env.request_method == 'OPTIONS':
        if request.env.http_access_control_request_method:
            print request.env.http_access_control_request_method
            response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = request.env.http_access_control_request_method
            if request.env.http_access_control_request_headers:
                response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = request.env.http_access_control_request_headers
```

==========================

RESTful POST & GET are now working
but PUT and DELETE aren't  because preflight http OPTIONS request is rejected as "400 BAD REQUEST" by web2py

So for example when calling the restful webservice using ajax call from a local web page,
we get the following error msg in NetBeans log.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (BAD REQUEST) (10:46:36:182 | error, network)   at
>   127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/api/entries/2.json Failed to load resource: Origin localhost:8383 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (10:46:36:183 | error, network)   at
>   127.0.0.1:8000/test/default /api/entries/2.json XMLHttpRequest cannot load 127.0.0.1:8000/test/default /api/entries/2.json. Origin
>   localhost:8383 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   (10:46:36:183 | error, javascript)   at www/page/test.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line:

response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but I just managed to solve the exact same problem. In my case the issue was with the controllers; I had to add the following wrapper before any actions:

```
def CORS(f):
    """
    Enables CORS for any action
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        if request.env.http_origin and request.env.request_method == 'OPTIONS':
            response.view = 'generic.json'
            return dict()
        return f(*args, **kwds)
    return wrapper
```

Then in your controller justy write

```
@CORS
def whatever():
    do_stuff
    return dict(stuff)
```